# Proving that $Df_v(a)=Df(a)(v)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

From Kolk's book:

[image]
and

[image]

I want to prove this proposition (in the book he does not prove it, just gives a vague hint).

We know that $Df(a)$ is the linear map such that 
$$
\underset{\parallel h\parallel\rightarrow0}{\lim}\frac{\parallel f(a+h)-f(a)-Df(a)(h)\parallel}{\parallel h\parallel}=0
$$
But this is clearly equivalent to saying that there exists
a map $\epsilon_{a}:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{p}$ such
that

\begin{equation}
f(a+h)-f(a)-Df(a)(h)=\epsilon_{a}(h)\label{eq:DeffDif3}
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
\underset{\parallel h\parallel\rightarrow0}{\lim}\frac{\parallel\epsilon_{a}(h)\parallel}{\parallel h\parallel}=0
\end{equation}

We want to prove that $Df(a)(v)=D_{v}f(a)$. We plug $D_{v}f(a)$
into (the last equation and get

$$
f(a+v)-f(a)-Df_{v}(a)=f(a+v)-f(a)-\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{f(a+tv)-f(a)}{t}=:\epsilon_{a}(v)
$$

But applying the norm and the limit to this, I can not manage to prove that

$$
\underset{\parallel v\parallel\rightarrow0}{\lim}\frac{\parallel\epsilon_{a}(v)\parallel}{\parallel v\parallel}=0
$$

Because the terms do not cancel out as I was expecting.
Any hints?

**EDIT:** In the book, Kolk says to use

[image]

Comment: Can’t you use the chain rule to prove this?

Comment: @amd This is before chain rule in the book

Comment: I'm seeing the sign $\supset\!\to$ for the first time here. What is its exact definition?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter It means that it is a function from a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^p$

Answer (score 4):

Just use the multivariable chain rule i.e $(f \circ g)'(t_0) = Df(g(t_0)) \cdot Dg(t_0)$. Here we have that $f = \begin{pmatrix} f^1 & f^2 \cdots & f^n \end{pmatrix}$ and $g(t) = a + t \textbf{v}$.

\begin{align*}D_{\textbf{v}}f(a) = \frac{d}{dt}\Bigr|_{t=0} f(a+t\textbf{v}) &=  (f \circ g)'(0) \\&= Df(g(0))  \cdot Dg(0) \\ & =  Df(a) \cdot g'(0) \\&=Df(a) \cdot \textbf{v} \end{align*}

Comment: This is before chain rule in the book, so I would like to prove it without using the chain rule. That said, thank you for your answer, it is useful anyway!

Comment: Do you have taylor's theorem? What book are you using?

Comment: Kolk's book on multivariable calculus

Comment: And I do not have Taylor's theorem. I am certain that we must do something like I did - the hint he gives is to use my second and third equations. I will edit my question with the hint.

Comment: Shouldn't it be \begin{align*}D_{\textbf{v}}f(a) = \frac{d}{dt}\Bigr|_{t=0} f(a+t\textbf{v}) &= D(f\circ g)(0)(1) = (Df (g(0))\circ D g(0))(1) = Df(a)(D g(0)(1))=Df(a)(\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}g(t))=Df(a)(v)\end{align*}
?

Answer (score 0):

The proof is fairly straightforward in asymptotic (“little oh”) notation.

By definition, $f(\mathbf a+t\mathbf v)-f(\mathbf a)=tD_{\mathbf v}f(\mathbf a)+\phi(t)$, where $\phi\in o(t)$. On the other hand, $f(\mathbf a+t\mathbf v)-f(\mathbf a)=Df(\mathbf a)[t\mathbf v]+\psi(t\mathbf v)=tDf(\mathbf a)[\mathbf v]+\psi(t\mathbf v)$. The error term is the composition of a little-oh function with a linear function of $t$ and so is in $o(t)$. Subtracting the two equations, we have $tD_{\mathbf v}f(\mathbf a)-tDf(\mathbf a)[\mathbf v]\in o(t)$. The left-hand side is a linear function of $t$, and a linear function that is in little-oh must be identically zero, therefore $D_{\mathbf v}f(\mathbf a)=Df(\mathbf a)[\mathbf v]$.

It shouldn’t be too hard to convert this argument to use limits explicitly. The two error terms don’t cancel, but an application of the triangle inequality should suffice to show that the total error, and so the difference between the two expressions, vanishes in the limit.

*Update:* Using the definitions that are more familiar to you, $\phi$ in the first equation is an unspecified function such that $\lim_{|t|\to0}\|\phi(t)\|\,/\,|t|=0$ and $\psi$ in the second satisfies $\lim_{\|t\mathbf v\|\to0}\|\psi(t\mathbf v)\|\,/\,\|t\mathbf v\|$. To have equality between $Df(\mathbf a)[\mathbf v]$ and $D_{\mathbf v}f(\mathbf a)$ their difference must vanish in the limit, i.e., we must have $$\lim_{|t|\to0}{\|\phi(t)-\psi(t\mathbf v)\|\over|t|}=0.$$ However, $$0\le{\|\phi(t)-\psi(t\mathbf v)\|\over|t|}\le{\|\phi(t)\|\over|t|}+{\|\psi(t\mathbf v)\|\over|t|}={\|\phi(t)\|\over|t|}+\|\mathbf v\|{\|\psi(t\mathbf v)\|\over\|t\mathbf v\|}$$ (as per the hint), so this quantity vanishes in the limit, as needed.

Comment: I am not familiar with that notation... A quick search in Google did not give me satisfactory results, also.

Comment: @Simoes For reference, a function $\phi(\mathbf v)$ is said to be in $o(\mathbf v)$ is given any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $\|\mathbf v\|\le\delta\implies\|\phi(\mathbf v)\|\le\epsilon\|\mathbf v\|$, i.e., that $\lim_{\|\mathbf v\|\to0}{\|\phi(\mathbf v)\|\over\|\mathbf v\|}$. There are other asymptotic classes besides this one, and several useful lemmas about their combinations, such as the one I use about the composition of a linear and little-oh function. I find using these asymptotics greatly reduces notational clutter.

Comment: @Simoes This proof pretty much follows the hint you later added. The function $\psi$ here is the same as $\epsilon_a$ in the hint. The difference is that instead of taking limits directly, I use standard properties of little-oh. The key step in both proofs is that, since $\mathbf v$ is constant, you can “pull out” a factor of $\|\mathbf v\|$ from the limit (or in the hint’s case, put one in).

Comment: You say: "By definition, $f(\mathbf a+t\mathbf v)-f(\mathbf a)=tD_{\mathbf v}f(\mathbf a)+\phi(t)$" but I do not see why:  by definition, we have an arbitrary $h$ where you wrote $tv$, and it seems to me that having $t\rightarrow 0$ with $tv$ where I had $h$ is not the same as having $h$ everywhere (was I clear enough?).
You also say that "$f(\mathbf a+t\mathbf v)-f(\mathbf a)=Df(\mathbf a)[t\mathbf v]+\psi(t\mathbf v)=tDf(\mathbf a)[\mathbf v]+\psi(t\mathbf v)$".But the definition of $Df(\mathbf a)[t\mathbf v]$ is not this, as far as I know: it is the definition231 that I have in my question

Comment: @Simoes You’ve gotten the two definitions backwards. The first equation is precisely your Def. 2.3.1—that of a directional derivative—rewritten in terms of little-oh (just multiply through by $t$). The second is straight from the definition of a function’s differential, but using the vector $t\mathbf v$ as the displacement from $\mathbf a$ since that’s the only direction that we care about here.